# go to activity to activity in android (and also go back to previous activity)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I had been looking around to find the solution and I begin to confused the more I read. I start with a main class call Restaurant.java and at the main page I have 3 buttons which are Foods, Beverages, Bill. I am trying to display the view of the food.xml when I click food button, view beverages with beverages button. I create Foods.java for food as a class.

My main intention is to click one of the display 3 buttons on the main page and to the foods page(foods.xml) and click the back button on the foods.xml to go back to the main page. Food part is working fine but my beverages and bill pages fail though they have roughly all the code similar. (I get Emulator without GPU emulation detected.)I am very new in android and I have been trying very hard to know the actual android concept working around. I have been reading Beginning android 3 book to learn android.

MY MAIN CLASS ---RESTAURANT.JAVA

```
package com.restaurant.first;
import com.restaurant.first.R;
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Restaurant extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View foodButton =(View)findViewById(R.id.foods);
    View beveragesButton =(View)findViewById(R.id.beverages);
    View billButton =(View)findViewById(R.id.bill);
    foodButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    beveragesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    billButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.foods:    Intent foods = new Intent(this, Foods.class);
                            startActivity(foods);
                            break;
        case R.id.beverages:Intent beverages = new Intent(this, Beverages.class);
                            startActivity(beverages);
                            break;
        case R.id.bill:     Intent bill = new Intent(this, Bill.class);
                            startActivity(bill);
                            break;
    }
}
```

}

MY FOOD CLASS

```
package com.restaurant.first;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Foods extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foods);
        View backButton =(View)findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.backButton:   Intent menu = new Intent(this, Restaurant.class);
                                startActivity(menu);
                                break;
    }

}
}
```

BEVERAGES.JAVA

```
package com.restaurant.first;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Beverages extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.beverages);
        View backButton =(View)findViewById(R.id.backButton);
       backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.backButton:   Intent menu = new Intent(this, Restaurant.class);
                                startActivity(menu);
                                break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I actually is going to input the foods.xml with all the foods in database. and take orders from customer how many and how much they should pay...Please help me to solve this question. thank you. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because of a `.` instead of `:`

in the `demo` Layout there was a typo as `android.id` which should be `android:id`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a new menu-Intent, you should just `finish()` your beverages-activity.

Something like:

```
case R.id.backButton:   finish();
                        break;
```

This will finish your activity and bring you back to your main activty (Restaurant.java).

Comment: All my food, beverages, bill class has the finish();. I manage to run the program and food is fine but the beverages and bill when I click the beverages button, the program terminates. or is it my manifest cause problem?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it is your Manifest file. You need to register your activities in the manifest file. The way you have registered "food" activity